# CRM 2013 Deactivation of Record

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

I am confused with this feature in CRM13, please help.

**In CRM11**,

I added some options in the "StatusReason" field for "Inactive".

When i try to deactivate that record from the grid, it will ask you to select the status for deactivation.

When i try to deactivate the record from the form itself, then also same thing happened.

Now my CRM upgraded to CRM13.

**In CRM13** ,

deactivation of record from grid will allow you to select the status that is added for the "Inactive" but,

deactivation of record from the form itself, will not allow you to select the status that is added for the "Inactive" rather than this, it will deactivate the record automatically.

Is there any big change happened in this CRM13 for this feature?

Any kind of idea will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Anish

Comment: I had one CRM11 online account and i tested it out and i found that deactivation of record from form itself, it will still allow you to select the status.

But

Same thing does not happens in CRM13 now.

Any idea??

Comment: Are you trying to deactivate a custom entity or an opportunity/contact/lead/account?

Comment: This is custom entity.

Comment: I reported this bug on Connect during the beta for CRM 2013. It was fixed in the Online 2 release. Not sure about on-premises rollups, but suspect SP1 will cover it. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2925872

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar experience when deactivating the record from form level. There is no MSDN CRM article related to this. CRM 2013 brand new menu is designed to ease user navigation, free up screen space, **remove pop-up windows**, etc. Probably part of this strategy this feature has been depreciated. There is nothing being mentioned in CRM Rollup 13. http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=2891271.

The workaround is to hide the deactivate button and make a custom button to invoke a dialogue to set the relevant status reasons.

Comment: I'll wait a couple of days and award if nothing better comes along.  The dialog processes aren't as seamless as the built-in dialogs that it uses.  It would be nice if there were a way to do a similar dialog without having to manipulate the DOM

Comment: Thanks. Another solution is add a custom option set field for deactivate. Create a sync workflow (Supported in CRM 2013) to deactivate the record with selected option set value.

Comment: That is a lot easier than messing with the ribbon.  Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: The idea for sync workflow is good. I will try this if it works..thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This was a bug in my CRM Online instance.

Now automatically this has been fixed. 
I do not know how this is fixed..but I guess after some updates..this got fixed.

Comment: I can't remember if this was in UR2 or service pack 1, but I have seen it referred to in the list of fixes.

Comment: I faced and wrote the same, please clarify why this answer is downvoted?
Everyone knows that CRM13 had many issues...Isn't it?